# How to count the number of decimal places in a Float?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.5.

If I have a float like 12.525, how can a get the number of digits past the decimal place? In this case I expect to get a '3' back.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a very simple approach. Keep track of how many times you have to multiple the number by 10 before it equals its equivalent integer:

```
def decimals(a)
    num = 0
    while(a != a.to_i)
        num += 1
        a *= 10
    end
    num   
end

decimals(1.234) # -> 3
decimals(10/3.0) # -> 16
```

Comment: Thanks, I stuck than in my application helper file.   Nice to have there to be called when needed.

Comment: Take care, don't pass Rationals into this logic. For example `Rational(1, 3)` will never terminate.

Comment: For rationals and such you can define a maximum. `a = a.round(maximum)` and maximum is passed as an optional param.

Comment: Since some rational numbers cannot be represented accurately in binary representation, above code returns 15 for 10.12 instead of 2 (because 10.12 is represented by 10.119999999999999). Any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: In fact the issue comes from the propagation of the "error". If instead of recursively multiplying the original value (i.e., `a *= 10`) if we keep the original input a in another variable called `original_a` and replace the multiplication like with `a = original_a * 10 ** num` then the function return 3 for 10.12. It is still not correct but a lot better... That is, in irb `(10.12*1000).modulo(1)` returns `0.0` while `(10.12*10*10*10).modulo(1)` returns `0.999999999998181`

Comment: There is a big downside with this function. If you inadvertently pass a string as argument, e.g. `decimals("2")`, the while loop condition will never be true.

Answer (score 27):

Something like that, I guess:

```
n = 12.525
n.to_s.split('.').last.size
```

Comment: Be aware that this will return 1 if `n` is an integer, when you'd probably want a zero. This tripped me up when I had mixed integers and floats.

Comment: `return 0 if not num.to_s.include? '.'`

Comment: This doesn't work for very small numbers. Example: `n = 0.000001; n.to_s # => "1.0e-06"`. You should use: `format("%f", n)` to get a consistent format.

Answer (score 14):

You should be very careful with what you want. [Floating point numbers](http://floating-point-gui.de/) are excellent for scientific purposes and mostly work for daily use, but they fall apart pretty badly when you want to know something like "how many digits past the decimal place" -- if only because they have [about 16 digits total](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_formats), not all of which will contain *accurate* data for your computation. (Or, some libraries might actually throw away accurate data towards the end of the number when formatting a number for output, on the grounds that "rounded numbers are more friendly". Which, while often true, means it can be a bit dangerous to rely upon formatted output.)

If you can replace the standard floating point numbers with the `BigDecimal` class to provide arbitrary-precision floating point numbers, then you can inspect the "raw" number:

```
> require 'bigdecimal'
=> true
> def digits_after_decimal_point(f)
>   sign, digits, base, exponent = f.split
>   return digits.length - exponent
> end
> l = %w{1.0, 1.1, 1000000000.1, 1.0000000001}
=> ["1.0,", "1.1,", "1000000000.1,", "1.0000000001"]
> list = l.map { |n| BigDecimal(n) }
=> [#<BigDecimal:7f7a56aa8f70,'0.1E1',9(18)>, #<BigDecimal:7f7a56aa8ef8,'0.11E1',18(18)>, #<BigDecimal:7f7a56aa8ea8,'0.1000000000 1E10',27(27)>, #<BigDecimal:7f7a56aa8e58,'0.1000000000 1E1',27(27)>]
> list.map { |i| digits_after_decimal_point(i) }
=> [0, 1, 1, 10]
```

Of course, if moving to `BigDecimal` makes your application too slow or is patently too powerful for what you need, this might overly complicate your code for no real benefit. You'll have to decide what is most important for your application.

Comment: TAKE CARE: The value 0 returns 1 (should be 0) and the value 10 returns -1.

Comment: If you already have the number as a string (which you must if you're to initialize BigDecimal without a `precision` argument), why not just do `n[/\d+$/].size`?

Answer (score 2):

Like This:

```
theFloat.to_s.split(".")[1].length
```

It is not very pretty, but you can insert it as a method for Float:

```
class Float
    def decimalPlaces
      self.to_s.split(".")[1].length
    end
end
```

Comment: This approach gives me 14 for (10/3.0) but my answer gives 16. I think repeating decimals will be problematic no matter how you approach it.

Comment: Well, thats odd... I need to go use IRB!

Comment: Each approach is depending on different things, so the different answers aren't too surprising.

Comment: Wait. By (10/3.0) do you mean an object of Ruby's Rational class?

Comment: No I mean 3.3333..... (10/3.0) is a simple way to get it. For your answer, `(10/3.0).decimalPlaces` returns 14, but my `decimals(10/3.0)` returns 16

Comment: Well, for an irrational number, should *any* decimal place counter work? I think it is just the difference between the number of decimal places given by `to_s` and that are stored in good old inexact floats. I think thats the difference. You have to remember that Ruby's floats are just as bad as C's floats. For something really exact, you want `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm getting at. I'm not trying to suggest either solution is better. Just interesting that the difference came up.

Comment: I'm just happy to involve myself in an interesting conversation about programming. SO sure seems to be the place to do that. But the fact that the difference came from float inaccuracy is quite interesting, if you ask me. It was quite something to ask decimal place counting code to count an irrational number in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Can you subtract the floor and then just count how many characters left?

(12.525 -( 12.52­5.floor )).to­_s.length-­2
=> 3

edit: nope this doesnt work for a bunch of reasons, negatives and 0.99999 issues

Answer (score 0):

Olexandr's answer doesn't work for integer. Can try the following:

```
def decimals(num)
  if num
    arr = num.to_s.split('.')
    case arr.size
      when 1
        0
      when 2
        arr.last.size
      else
        nil
    end
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this approach**

```
def digits_after_decimal_point(n)
  splitted = n.to_s.split(".")
  if splitted.count > 1
    return 0 if splitted[1].to_f == 0
    return splitted[1].length
  else
   return 0
  end
end



# Examples
digits_after_decimal_point("1") #=> 0
digits_after_decimal_point("1.0") #=> 0
digits_after_decimal_point("1.01") #=> 2
digits_after_decimal_point("1.00000") #=> 0
digits_after_decimal_point("1.000001") #=> 6
digits_after_decimal_point(nil) #=> 0
```